# Python ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'exit'

Tags: python

The below code works for integers, negative and decimal numbers. The issue is that Id like it to jump to the else statement below if someone types exit or if someone types any string to either exit the program or give an I dont understand message. Appreciate the help.

```
temp = ""

while temp != "exit":
    temp = float(input("Enter a temperature or type exit: "))
    #check if its number or else kick it to the else statement
    if type(temp) == float or temp.isnumeric() == True :
        unit = input("Enter unit('C' for Celsius or 'F' for Fahrenheit): ")
        if unit == 'C' or unit == 'c' :
            newTemp = int(round((9 * temp) / 5 + 32))
            print("The temperature in Fahrenheit is", newTemp)
        else:
            if unit == 'F' or unit == 'f' :
             newTemp = int(round((temp - 32) * 5 / 9))
             print("Temperature in Celsius =", newTemp)
    else:
        if temp.lower() == "exit":
            temp = temp.lower()
            print("Goodbye!")
        else:
            print("I dont understand. Try again.\n")
```

Comment: You need to defer applying `float()` to the user's input until *after* you have determined that the user actually typed a number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. It converts the input to string, then tries to convert it to float (both integers and floats can be converted to floats, hence it checks if it is numeric).
If it can't be converted to float, then it is a string and stays that way for the if-else statements.

```
temp = ""

while temp != "exit":
    temp = str(input("Enter a temperature or type exit: "))
    try:
        temp=float(temp)
    except ValueError:
        pass
    #check if its number or else kick it to the else statement
    if type(temp) == float:
        unit = input("Enter unit('C' for Celsius or 'F' for Fahrenheit): ")
        if unit == 'C' or unit == 'c' :
            newTemp = int(round((9 * temp) / 5 + 32))
            print("The temperature in Fahrenheit is", newTemp)
        else:
            if unit == 'F' or unit == 'f' :
             newTemp = int(round((temp - 32) * 5 / 9))
             print("Temperature in Celsius =", newTemp)
    else:
        if temp.lower() == "exit":
            temp = temp.lower()
            print("Goodbye!")
        else:
            print("I dont understand. Try again.\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when the user enters `'exit'`, this line fails:

```
    temp = float(input("Enter a temperature or type exit: "))
```

That makes sense, because `float('exit')` doesn't have a valid result. One way to avoid that would be to check if the input is a valid number before converting it. But an easy way to do both in one go would be to catch the exception when it happens.

```
text = ""

while text != "exit":
    try:
        # keeping the input in a separate variable, to avoid type checking
        text = input("Enter a temperature or type exit: ")
        # this may trigger a ValueError exception, but that can be a good thing
        temp = float(text)

        # this code will only be executed if there was no ValueError
        unit = input("Enter unit('C' for Celsius or 'F' for Fahrenheit): ")
        if unit == 'C' or unit == 'c' :
            newTemp = int(round((9 * temp) / 5 + 32))
            print("The temperature in Fahrenheit is", newTemp)
        else:
            if unit == 'F' or unit == 'f' :
             newTemp = int(round((temp - 32) * 5 / 9))
             print("Temperature in Celsius =", newTemp)
    except ValueError:
        # this code will be executed if there was a ValueError
        if text.lower() == "exit":
            text = text.lower()
            print("Goodbye!")
        else:
            print("I dont understand. Try again.\n")
```

Note that this assumes there's only one reason for a ValueError to occur - you need to be careful with this type of broad exception catching. A safer solution might be to catch it for just the one command:

```
while True:
    text = input("Enter a temperature or type exit: ")
    try:
        temp = float(text)
    except ValueError:
        if text.lower() == "exit":
            text = text.lower()
            print("Goodbye!")
            break
        else:
            print("I dont understand. Try again.\n")
            continue

    unit = input("Enter unit('C' for Celsius or 'F' for Fahrenheit): ")
    if unit == 'C' or unit == 'c' :
        newTemp = int(round((9 * temp) / 5 + 32))
        print("The temperature in Fahrenheit is", newTemp)
    else:
        if unit == 'F' or unit == 'f' :
         newTemp = int(round((temp - 32) * 5 / 9))
         print("Temperature in Celsius =", newTemp)
```

Now, the part in the `except` block only deals with non-numeric text entry and once that completes, any additional errors will still get raised and you can deal with them separately as needed.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer!

Answer (score 0):

As others already stated you tried to convert `"exit"` to a `float` and that will throw an error. You have to catch this error.

Here is a more idiomatic version of your code.

```
while True:
    user_input = input("Enter a temperature or type exit: ")
    if user_input.lower() == 'exit':
        print("Goodbye!")
        break
    try:
        temperature_to_convert = float(user_input)
    except ValueError:
        print("Invalid temparature value. Try again.\n")
        continue

    unit = input("Enter unit('C' for Celsius or 'F' for Fahrenheit): ").lower()
    if unit == 'c':
        temperature = int(round((9 * temperature_to_convert) / 5 + 32))
        print(f"The temperature in Fahrenheit is {temperature}")
    elif unit == 'f':
        temperature = int(round((temperature_to_convert - 32) * 5 / 9))
        print(f"The temperature in Celsius is {temperature}")
    else:
        print("Invalid unit. Try again.\n")
```